# Using javascript regex to translate a html

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to build my own translation function in javascript.
I already have a function language.lookup(key) which translates a word or expression:

```
var frenchHello = language.lookup('hello') //'bonjour'
```

Now I would like to write a function which takes a html string and translates it with my lookup function. In the html string I will have a special syntax for example #[translationkey] that will point out that this word should be translated.

This is the result I want:

```
var html = '<div><span>#[hello]</span><span>#[sir]</span>'
language.translate(html) //'<div><span>bonjour</span><span>monsieur</span>
```

How would I write language.translate?
My idea is to filter out my special syntax with regex and then run language.lookup on each key. Maybe with string replace or something.

I suck when it comes to regex and I've only come up with a very incomplete example but I include it anyway so maybe someone get the idea of what I am trying to do. Then if there is a better but complete different solution that is more than welcome.

```
var value = "#[hello], nice to see you.";

lookup = function(word){
    return "bonjour";
};

var res = new RegExp( "\\b(hello)\\b", "gi" ).exec(value)

for (var c1 = 0; c1 < res.length; c1++){
    value = value.replace(res[c1], lookup(res[c1]))
}       
alert(value) //#[bonjour], nice to see you.
```

The regex should of course not filter out the word hello but the syntax and then collect the key by grouping or similar.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method's ability to call function specified as second argument to generate replacement text and make a global replace using regexp matching your syntax:

```
var value = "#[hello], #[sir], nice to see you.";

lookup = function(full_match, word){
    if(word == 'hello')
        return "bonjour";
    if(word == 'sir')
        return "monsieur"
};

console.log(value.replace(/#\[(.+?)\]/gi, lookup))
```

Result:
bonjour, monsieur, nice to see you.

Of course when your replacement list gets bigger, you'd better use lookup object instead of series of ifs in lookup function, but you can really do whatever you want there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
#\\[[^\\]]*\\]
```

Which matches the hash followed by an opening square bracket followed by zero or more characters NOT including the closing square bracket, followed by a closed square bracket.

Alternatively, perhaps it would be better to handle the translation at the server side (maybe even through your template engine) and send back to your client the translated response. Otherwise, (depending on the specific problem you are dealing with of course), you might end up sending a lot of data to the browser which might make your application respond slowly.

EDIT:
Here is a working piece of code:

```
    var q="This #[ANIMAL1] was eaten by that #[ANIMAL2]";
    var u = {"#[ANIMAL1]":"Lion","#[ANIMAL2]":"Frog"};

    function insertAnimal(aString, lookup){
        var res = (new RegExp("#\\[[^\\]]*\\]", "gi"))          
        while (m = res.exec(aString)){
            aString = aString.replace(m, lookup[m])
        }       
        return aString;
    }  

    function main(){
        alert(insertAnimal(q,u));           
    }
```

You can call the "main()" from an HTML document's body onload event

Comment: Yes it is better to do this server side. Or else you'll have the client loading two languages, one that will be replaced.

Comment: Can you please edit the answer to a complete runnable example since I can't get it to work with your suggestion.

Comment: People, use ? modifier. Every time I see "not including" ranges instead of simple frugal modifier my eyes bleed of pain.

Comment: @John Perhaps a bit late but here it is anyway. There were a few "\" missing in the previous one. (OlegV.Volkov Sorry for all the pain :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to find all occurrences:

```
var re = new RegExp('#\\[([^\\]]+?)\\]', 'gi'),
    str = '#[value1] plain text #[value2]',
    match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

Comment: I actually get null from re.exec(str) first time in the loop condition. Is the expression really correct?

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the '[\\]]', replaced it with '.'

Comment: Ok, error localized and fixed :) It was missing '^' inside brackets

Answer (score 0):

I can compare your requirement to 'resolving template texts within content'. If it is feasible to use Jquery , you should try [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
.